# subprocess usage in web2py

Tags: python, frameworks, web2py

I am trying to run a python script from web2py's controller function using subprocess.call method. But the script does not execute from there, but when I am running the same method from inside python shell, it runs without any problems.

The command I wrote in web2py controller's function is:

```
subprocess.call(['python','script.py', args])
```

where args is a string containing command line arguments I want to pass to the script
The command I wrote in python shell is:

```
>>>subprocess.call(['python','script.py','args'])
```

here I am directly passing the arguments.

script.py creates multiple files in directory, but it doesn't do so with web2py.

I have used subprocess multiple times within the web2py controller function without any problem and I have also tried changing the permission of script.py to 777, but it was not of any help either.

Can anyone tell me where my mistake is?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to provide full path to script.py?

Comment: In addition, I would also use ``sys.executable`` to get the full path of the Python interpreter.

Comment: What happens if you replace 'python' with 'echo'?

Comment: Also, maybe it's something to do with script.py file permissions? Can you try chmod a+x script.py? Also, how exactly do you know that script.py doesn't run?

Comment: I tried changing the file permissions, but it isn't working then also.

Comment: script.py should generate some files in my folder, but through web2py those files are not generated but these do generate using python shell.
I have used subprocess.call several times, and every time it runs properly except for this case

Comment: script.py does not return anything, If my knowledge is right subprocess.call executes in background and does not effect web2py's function

Comment: Maybe the user from which you run script.py doesn't have permission to write to the directory where you want to save output files?

Comment: I am able to create file explicitly through subprocess without any problem

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide all details we discussed here so it gets more attention from other users?

Comment: @VladimirKadalashvili: I am passing the arguments in web2py's controller function in form of string variable, does this in any way effect the functioning of subprocess.call?